# Does it make sense to calculate the phospho protein (serine) : phospho protein (threonine) of the same protein in western blot?

Tags: proteins, western-blot, intracellular-transport, phosphorylation

I want to indirectly measure the nuclear accumulation of DARPP protein through phosphorylation. Their nuclear transport is controlled by phosphorylation of Threonine 34 and Serine 97 residues.

S97 is then dephosphorylated while T34 is phosphorylated as it moves into the nucleus.

So I want to determine cell localization indirectly through the ratio of Serine 97 and Threonine 34.

I know that the ratio of phosphoprotein to total protein is often estimated by immunoblot analysis. I have antibodies specific to each of these phospho-proteoforms of DARPP.

Does it make sense to calculate the phospho protein (serine residue) : phospho protein (threonine residue) of the same protein? Has anyone ever done this kind of analysis? I cannot find the reference anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find out? It makes no sense at all if you don't tell us.

Comment: Are the serines and threonines variants at the same position? are they at different positions? How are you imagining distinguishing between them? Do you have p-T and p-S specific antibodies?

Comment: @David I wanted to indirectly measure the nuclear accumulation of DARPP protein through phosphorylation. Their nuclear transport is controlled by phosphorylation of Threonine 34 and Serine 97 residues. When S97 is dephosphorylated and T34 is only phosphorylated, it moves into the nucleus. So I wanted to find out indirectly through the ratio of Serine 97 and Threonine 34.

Comment: @Maximilian Press They're at different position. One is T34, and the other is S97. And yes, I have specific phospho- antibodies for both.

Comment: editing your question to add this crucial information. Some of it doesn't make much sense to me so please edit my edits as needed.

Comment: @MaximilianPress Thanks for adding the information! Nobody knows the answer tho..

Comment: @oklu most people probably looked at it when first posted and evaluated it as too vague, and never clicked on it again. Someone likely knows the answer but you may need to wait until more people look at it. In the meantime you could try to do google searches on your own.